# AssignProcessToJobObject don't assign properly

Tags: c#, object, jobs, flags, assign

i tried to set "job_object_limit_kill_on_job_close" to an child process using this:

```
int pid = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Child")[0].Id;
Job job = new Job("TEST JOB");
job.AddProcess(Process.GetProcessById((int)pid).Handle);
```

Using Process Explorer i saw the job "TEST JOB" assigned to my child process but there is no Job Limit listed somehow...its just empty.

What could cause this?

`GetLastWin32Error` just return `0`

Here's the class i'm using:

```
public class Job : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateJobObject(IntPtr a, string lpName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetInformationJobObject(IntPtr hJob, JobObjectInfoType infoType, IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo, UInt32 cbJobObjectInfoLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AssignProcessToJobObject(IntPtr job, IntPtr process);

    private IntPtr handle;
    private bool disposed;

    public Job(string jobName)
    {
        handle = CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, jobName);

        var info = new JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            LimitFlags = 0x2000
        };

        var extendedInfo = new JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            BasicLimitInformation = info
        };

        int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION));
        IntPtr extendedInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(extendedInfo, extendedInfoPtr, false);

        if (!SetInformationJobObject(handle, JobObjectInfoType.ExtendedLimitInformation, extendedInfoPtr, (uint)length))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to set information.  Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing) { }

        Close();
        disposed = true;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    public void Close()
    {
        CloseHandle(handle);
        handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public bool AddProcess(IntPtr processHandle)
    {
        return AssignProcessToJobObject(handle, processHandle);
    }

    public bool AddProcess(int processId)
    {
        return AddProcess(Process.GetProcessById(processId).Handle);
    }

}

#region Helper classes

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct IO_COUNTERS
{
    public UInt64 ReadOperationCount;
    public UInt64 WriteOperationCount;
    public UInt64 OtherOperationCount;
    public UInt64 ReadTransferCount;
    public UInt64 WriteTransferCount;
    public UInt64 OtherTransferCount;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
{
    public Int64 PerProcessUserTimeLimit;
    public Int64 PerJobUserTimeLimit;
    public UInt32 LimitFlags;
    public UIntPtr MinimumWorkingSetSize;
    public UIntPtr MaximumWorkingSetSize;
    public UInt32 ActiveProcessLimit;
    public UIntPtr Affinity;
    public UInt32 PriorityClass;
    public UInt32 SchedulingClass;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public UInt32 nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public Int32 bInheritHandle;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
{
    public JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION BasicLimitInformation;
    public IO_COUNTERS IoInfo;
    public UIntPtr ProcessMemoryLimit;
    public UIntPtr JobMemoryLimit;
    public UIntPtr PeakProcessMemoryUsed;
    public UIntPtr PeakJobMemoryUsed;
}

public enum JobObjectInfoType
{
    AssociateCompletionPortInformation = 7,
    BasicLimitInformation = 2,
    BasicUIRestrictions = 4,
    EndOfJobTimeInformation = 6,
    ExtendedLimitInformation = 9,
    SecurityLimitInformation = 5,
    GroupInformation = 11
}

#endregion
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Okay im sorry :S new in here

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, Process Explorer just doesn't show the kill on close flag.  What it will show are [job memory and process limits](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZNLkWZU0gyMC&pg=PT167&lpg=PT167&dq=sysinternals%20process%20job%20limits&source=bl&ots=Rf6WVCNgNl&sig=tFAyvW_GiFnpkbQzNNAyFYPm-pA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xY4jUbRi7a7QAY3YgOAN&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBQ).

Did you test and ensure that your child processes are ended when you end the job?  As long as your program is behaving correctly you don't need to worry what an external tool is showing.

Comment: nope did not work. The client process was still up idk why. But ty for tellin me that process explorer issue :)